# Best way to automate creation routine using Python

Tags: python, browser

Usually, everyday I have to create emails, save them into a file, then use them to register accounts, etc. It's really boring and takes a good amount of time. I don't want to waste it.

I want to automate this process. As I understand, it's called a "bot". What it should do is go through few websites, click some buttons, scrape needed information, store collected information and fill some forms. Is it possible to do so with Python? If yes, what's the most compact way to do this?

Comment: Most sites have Captcha protection to prevent bots from creating accounts, and many sites disguise email addresses to prevent bots from collecting them. Are you looking for ways around those problems, or are you working with sites that are perfectly OK with what you're doing? If the latter, there's a good bet they actually have an API, and it will be easier to use the API than to try to drive or simulate a browser.

Comment: It indeed is possible. 

Use a module like urllib to make requests. BeautifulSoup module will help you parse and scrape the required information from the websites. You can also send POST data to the form using urllib2.

Comment: This question probably belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Scrapy will definitely work for this. Check out deathbycaptcha.com for handling captcha automation.

Answer (score 0):

Python's selenium bindings are a great way to automate browser sessions, scrape page data, fill out forms, click buttons, etc. Selenium allows the page JS to run, then parses the DOM for you and makes it available as Python objects through a well-documented API:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Much much easier than trying to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The Scrapy python module should meet your needs:

http://scrapy.org/